# Empty View to add any Content on it

Tags: android, layout, view

I'm creating an application and it's has a button to switch perspective view of the itens (coverflow, grid and list). My question was, how do I keep an space in my activity to swap these views?

I have a header, and a footer, the middle I want to place an empty View in that to switch my perspectives on it.

Someone has a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) if I understand you right. Even better you can define your children Views as [includes](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) or [stubs](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand your question.

Are you looking for a ViewStub?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html

You can inflate layouts to a ViewStub. But you can do it to any "ViewGroup" like LinearLayout etc.

The advantage is that a "ViewStub is an invisible, zero-sized View that can be used to lazily inflate layout resources at runtime". It's really there for it.

Inflating "normal" layouts may have additional costs.

Comment: This solves, but I need swap more than one layout in the same place, always removing the last one.